# problem configuring mollie payment

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

I recently updated the civicrm plugin to version 5.16, the latest.
I am trying to configure a event so that it can be paid with IDEAL (that is via interpay - mollie).
For this I use admin>system>payment means>add to find a screen where I can add a mollie payment (I have to translate the menu options to english here, maybe a little bit different)
In the new payment means, I select 'omnipay - mollie',
 [image: screenshot of adding payment means]

I select an account, add the API-keys, and then, when I change 'creditcard' to the first in the select, being 'IDEAL-omnipay-molly', I get an error screen saying:

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Deze financiële rekening kan geen '' relatie hebben.
```

Obviously there is something wrong with the selected account, maybe there is no account number configured, but how can I configure that? Have I missed some documentation on this? Any advise is welcome!

thanks in advance, Ruud

Comment: Do you have any other extensions installed on your site?

Comment: When you go to admin - civicontribute - financial accounts and edit the one for Betaalmethode rekening, does it look all blank to you? I'm wondering if there's a bug somewhere since it's blank on the public demo (payment processor account) when I look there. The error seems to say there's no "relationship" for the financial account (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.16/CRM/Financial/BAO/FinancialTypeAccount.php#L280).

Comment: I've posted https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/65 which might be related to the problem. Maybe.

Comment: I have changed the code with the pushed fix, but with no result. I have enabled civicontribute, and indeed editing the financial account gives me a form with all blank fields.... By the way, the only plugin next to civicrm is 'classical editor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, in clicking around, the message suddenly disappeared. This is what I did:

- admin > civicontribute > payment methods (probably; the entry after *accounts* and *before accepted creditcards*)
- I edited the molly entry
- there I filled in the valueless select box with the account

After that, I was able to save the screen that caused the message. I am a bit desoriented about the relation between the various lists, but I can now continue the configuration. Thanks all for helping me into the right direction! Ruud

Comment: I forgot to mention that one of the most important actions was to enable civicontribute, which was pointed out by Demerit.  This can be done via admin>system>component (first option in menu, don't know the english term for sure). This gives a list of enabled and disabled components, in which I had to enable civicontribute.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either 'Asset Account is' account relationship is deleted or disabled. You can check by navigation to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups. Find for 'Account Relationship' option, click 'edit option' link besides it. Find for 'Asset Account is' if its disabled or deleted.

Solution:

1. If disabled then enable it using api or through sql.
2. If deleted then Add a new one with Label and Name as 'Asset Account is'.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thanks for your replay. Alas, I have looked in the option screen, and the account relationship exists and is enabled. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Can you see in civicrm_option_value table if you can find for Asset Account is?

Comment: SELECT id FROM civicrm_option_value WHERE name ='Asset Account is';

Comment: Hi Pradeep. The table contains a record that satisfies the query. The returned id is 442

Comment: Okay, its because you have civi contribute disabled, the function couldn't return the value

Comment: OK. So can I draw the conclusion that my main problem was the fact I had civicontribute not enabled? And since it is enabled now, the problem is solved? I thought at first the problem went away after doing something with payment methods, but maybe only the enabling of civicontribute was enough....

Comment: Yes, you need to have civi contribute component enabled if you want to take payments. Hence the form threw fatal error when trying to add payment processor.